# Android Wear - How to change device the watch is paired with?

Tags: bluetooth-pairing, android-wear

I have an LG G Watch, which was paired to my Nexus 4 phone with the Android Wear app, and was working perfectly.

I then got a new Nexus 5, and I wanted to switch everything (accounts, &c) to it. However, when I tried to pair the G Watch using the Android Wear app on the new phone, it didn't appear in the list of possible devices (even after unpairing it from my old phone).

The only way I found to do this was with the "Reset Device" option in the G Watch, but this loses "local" data (such as the number of steps, and other configuration).

Is there a less destructive way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this page](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6058799?hl=en), you need to reset the watch to factory settings if you want to pair it with another device, each time you wish to switch phones or tablets.

Comment: You're right. That is unfortunate, though.

Answer (score 1):

BeeLink works for me for exactly that use case:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trainday.androidapps.beelink

Comment: The link that worked for me is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beelinkapp.Beelink&hl=en but I don't see how it answers the question.

Comment: This has been removed from the play store because 4.4W2 broke it.

Answer (score 0):

Using ADB worked for me. Turn ADB on on the Watch through Developer Options. Then connect the watch to computer with Android SDK installed on computer while turning Bluetooth off on the initial phone. Type: adb shell "pm clear com.google.android.gms && reboot"
Turn Bluetooth on on second phone. Type following in ADB shell: adb shell "am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE"
Follow watch on-screen prompts. You can now pair your watch with your new phone!

Comment: And I've doubts reserved that you came up with this solution without external help:http://forum.xda-developers.com/android-wear/development/app-reset-wear-client-switch-phones-t3058962 Correct?